# JQuery droppable div inside a sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to create a simple sortable and draggable list composed of :

- a list of draggable item (linked to the sortable below)
- a sortable list of item

  - Some of those item will have a droppable div inside of them

I managed to do this so far : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThibaudMZN/ebsoud8L/35/)

HTML Code :

```
<h3>DRAGGABLE</h3>
<ul id="draggables">
  <li class="draggable">Item 1</li>
  <li class="draggable">Item 2</li>
  <li class="draggable">Item 3</li>
  <li class="draggable">Item 4</li>
  <li class="draggable">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<h3>SORTABLE</h3>
<ul id="itemsContainer">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>Item with drop zone</p>
    <div class="droppable">DROP HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="item">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

The JS Code is here :

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '#itemsContainer',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid'
});

$("#itemsContainer").sortable({
  revert: true
});

$(".droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).html("Dropped!");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $(ui.helper[0]).css("background-color", "green");
  }
});
```

The problem is, when an item is dropped inside the droppable div, it detects correctly that a drop is happening, but the item is still added to the sortable list. I thought the "greedy" option would prevent this from happening. Any ideas ?

EDIT : If I apply a styling to the ui.helper[0] object (aka the cloned draggable object), it stays on until the item is actually sorted in the sortable list.

Comment: The item is removed from the list when you delete the line helper:'clone'. I edited this in your Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d4fa9bcg/

Comment: That’s not what I’m looking for. When dropping the item on the droppable area, I just don’t want this item to be added to the list, only inside the droppable div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a bit of overkill, but this is what I could come up with.

When we `stop` dragging a draggable item, we need to see if the item is over a droppable area, if so append it to said area.

**Edit:** Now we can drop a sortable item from the same list into the drop zone by connecting the sortable list to the drop zone and accepting the sortable items.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/gu0vno3k/2/)

```js
var over = false; // is the item over a droppable area?
var el_over = null; // if over a drop area, what drop area?
var de = null; // the item to detach

$(".draggable-item").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".list-2",
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (over) {
      de = $(this).detach();
      el_over.append(de);
    }
    over = false;
    el_over = null;
  }
});

$(".list-2").sortable({
  connectWith: '.drop-zone, .list-2',
  cursor: "move",
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (over) {
      de = ui.item.detach();
      el_over.append(de);
    }
    over = false;
    el_over = null;
  }
});

$(".drop-zone").droppable({
  accept: ".draggable-item, .sortable-item",
  over: function(event, ui) {
    //console.log("over");
    over = true;
    el_over = $(this);
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
    //console.log("out");
    over = false;
    el_over = null;
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.draggable-item {
  background: #9bcdf0;
}

.sortable-item {
  background: #6c2020;
}

.drop-zone {
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1px 0;
}

.drop-zone .draggable-item {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-1">
  <li class="draggable-item">draggable 1</li>
  <li class="draggable-item">draggable 2</li>
  <li class="draggable-item">draggable 3</li>
  <li class="draggable-item">draggable 4</li>
  <li class="draggable-item">draggable 5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-2">
  <li class="sortable-item">sortable 1</li>
  <li class="sortable-item">sortable 2</li>
  <li class="sortable-item">sortable 3
    <div class="drop-zone"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="sortable-item">sortable 4</li>
  <li class="sortable-item">sortable 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Updated answer:** 
Turns out we don't need all that overkill XD. If we just initialize the `.drop-zone` as a sortable and connect it to itself and `list-2` we get the same outcome.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/gu0vno3k/27/).

```
$(".draggable-item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".list-2",
});

$(".list-2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.drop-zone, .list-2',
    cursor: "move",
});

$(".drop-zone").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable-item, .sortable-item",
});

$(".drop-zone").sortable({
    connectWith: '.drop-zone, .list-2',
  items: '.draggable-item, .sortable-item',
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of a solution of this kind, and it actually works perfectly. Seems indeed a bit overkill but that does the trick ! Thanks !!

Comment: Acutally, I would also like the sortable-item from list-2 to be dropped inside of this, would that cause any problem of dropping item inside itself ?

Comment: @TmZn I've updated my answer. The only issue I see is that it doesn't detect "over" as well when inside it's own sortable :/

Comment: I see what you mean, but it does the trick anyway ! Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @TmZn Check my updated fiddle, we don't need that extra stuff, just initialize the drop zone as a sortable as well.

Comment: - Unless of course you don't want to be able to sort the items within the drop zone. The only thing is that you will need to find the index where you want to append the item when dropping it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210677/discussion-between-souleste-and-tmzn).